# What's the term for the "vertical looking angle" in FPSs?

Tags: terminology, first-person-shooter

I guess the "vertical angle" of looking in an FPS could be called the pitch of the camera, but surely there is another term for it?

(I'm trying to mod ArmA II, but I can't find anything in their documentation and forums about the camera pitch or whatnot. The ArmA people call the horizontal angle "direction.")

Comment: "pitch" is the correct term.  In ArmA II, I believe you have to set the camera's "target" instead of the pitch/roll/yaw - the two points of the camera's location and its target determine the orientation.

Comment: It is also called y-axis.

Comment: well I think of "pitch" as rotation around the x-axis, and rotation around y is "yaw".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical term for this is indeed "pitch," but that doesn't mean that all games will use that term explicitly, which may be why you can't find it.

Sometimes you'll also hear "angle of attack" although the latter does have a [more specific meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_attack) and is often abused.